# How to disable 127.0.0.53 as DNS?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

For some reason, my DNS seems to be set to 127.0.0.53. It's not *really* a problem, since my local (i.e. on my laptop) DNS seems to redirect DNS requests to the default gateway. But I would like it to not go that way. I suppose I must have installed some DNS server at some time in the past...

When I run `$ nslookup`, default server is always 127.0.0.53.

I found a post suggesting that I set `DNSStubListener=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, but this resulted in no DNS requests coming through. I could of course enter my default gateway manually, but then I would have to change it every time I brought my laptop to work.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Adding the "hosts" line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Comment: Your DND server is not actually `127.0.0.53`.  Look at this question on Unix &Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612416/why-does-etc-resolv-conf-point-at-127-0-0-53

Comment: Please add to your post the "hosts" line of /etc/nsswitch.conf ..; Adding the libnss-resolve package alters this and might fix some local name lookups.

Comment: It's working the way it's supposed to. Don't mess with it. Do `resolvectl status | grep -i "DNS Serve"` to see what DNS Servers that you're actually using.

Comment: @heynnema: Is this default Ubuntu behavior?

Comment: Yes. Everybody's /etc/resolv.conf shows 127.0.0.53. It's all managed by systemd-resolved. Using my prior command you'll see what real DNS servers it all points to. I see too many people trying to manually edit /etc/resolv.conf (even though it says not to in the file), thinking that they can "fix" an unbroken DNS system.

Comment: @heynnema Ah - thank you. Can't you write this as an answer, so that I may mark it as the correct one?

Comment: @OZ1SEJ Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DNS Servers are managed by `systemd-resolved`, or by `dnsmasq` (*if you have that installed*).

If `dnsmasq` is installed, you must edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, else you'll have two DNS mechanisms fighting for port 53, so...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to this:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

/etc/resolv.conf normally contains 127.0.0.53, which is the local address for the local DNS mechanism. Do **NOT** manually edit this file (*it says so right in the file itself*).

To view what actual DNS servers are being used, do this...

```
resolvectl status | grep -i "DNS Serve"
```

More than likely it'll report 192.168.0.1 (*the address of your router, or the DNS servers of your VPN service, if you use a VPN*). Your router will probably use your ISP's DNS servers, unless you've manually changed that in your router's admin config page (*highly recommended*).